# Do pilots adjust the throttle setting during a Red Bull air race?

Tags: flight-controls, air-race

During a race do the pilots adjust their throttle settings to control speed, or do they leave the throttle wide open the entire time?

Answer (score 6):

The only reference I could find is [here (watch the video too)](http://www.redbullairrace.com/en_US/video/pilots-keep-throttle-full-racing):

> **Pilots keep throttle on full for racing.**

It is a race. Only the fastest one wins.

Comment: "It is a race. Only the fastest one wins." That's a non-explanation. Car racing is also a race in which only the fastest one wins but there, you don't have your foot to the floor the whole time.

Comment: Being the fastest is not enough. There are [rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Bull_Air_Race_World_Championship#Rules) limiting load factor (and thus turn radius) and entry speed. Pilots may need to slow down to avoid penalties.